# FFMPEG NVENC encoding with Windows10

Tags: ffmpeg

I had to reinstall windows 10 because windows. I have this exact same code working prior to the reinstall, however after I cant get it to work.

I am using the latest nvidia drivers 416.16
I have VisualStudio and Cuda Toolkit installed
2x 1080TIs

Using ffmpeg 4.0.2:

```
T:\ffmpeg\bin\4.0.2\ffmpeg.exe -c:v h264_cuvid -i "T:\Streams\01-ready\2018-10-10 21-19-21.mp4" -i "T:\Streams\10-source\kpg-logo.png" -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -b:v 24000k -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy "T:\Streams\02-encoded\2018-10-10 21-19-21_watermarked.mp4"
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180722
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'T:\Streams\01-ready\2018-10-10 21-19-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.84.100
  Duration: 00:28:41.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24422 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2560x1440, 24130 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 286 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'T:\Streams\10-source\kpg-logo.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 2560x1440 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264_cuvid) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_nvenc @ 000002851a001940] CreateInputBuffer failed: out of memory (10)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Error Message

```
 [h264_nvenc @ 000002851a001940] CreateInputBuffer failed: out of memory (10)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Still having issues, now even with the simple commands:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i "input" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow "output.mp4"
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180722
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'T:\Streams\01-ready\2018-10-15 20-49-44.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.84.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22978 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 2560x1440, 24216 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 156 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'T:\Streams\02-encoded\2018-10-15 20-49-44.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), cuda, 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 4000000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
[h264_cuvid @ 000001a99033b600] ctx->cvdl->cuvidMapVideoFrame(ctx->cudecoder, parsed_frame.dispinfo.picture_index, &mapped_frame, &pitch, &params) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Generic error in an external library
/* repeated many many times */
[h264_nvenc @ 000001a98fcfc100] Failed locking bitstream buffer: invalid param (8)
video encoding failed: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001a98fdcd380] Qavg: 64894.355
[aac @ 000001a98fdcd380] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Full windows batch file:

```
@echo off

set ffmpegversion=20181015-c27c7b4-win64-static

set sourcedir=T:\Streams\01-ready
set outputdir=T:\Streams\02-encoded
set finaldir=T:\ffmpeg\mp4-upload

set libdir=T:\ffmpeg\bin\%ffmpegversion%

set introvid=T:\Streams\10-source\kpg-intro-10pec-audio.mp4
set watermark=T:\Streams\10-source\kpg-logo.png
set introvidlen=3.00
set outputbitrate=24000

cd /d %libdir%

if not exist %outputdir% (
    mkdir %outputdir%
)

if not exist %finaldir% (
    mkdir %finaldir%
)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo Checking %sourcedir%\*.mp4
for %%f in (%sourcedir%\*.mp4) do ( 
    if not exist "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked.mp4" (
        %libdir%\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -i "%watermark%" -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" -b:v %outputbitrate%k -s 2560x1440 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked.mp4"
        TIMEOUT 2
    )

    if not exist "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked_ready.mp4" (
        %libdir%\ffmpeg.exe -i "%introvid%" -i "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked.mp4" -an -filter_complex " [0:v]trim=start=0:end=%introvidlen%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip]; [1:v]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip]; [0:v]trim=start=%introvidlen%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc]; [1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc]; [fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein]; [fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout]; [fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo]; [fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo];[fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade]; [firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3[output]; [0:a][1:a] acrossfade=d=1 [audio]" -map "[output]" -map "[audio]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v %outputbitrate%k -ar 44100 -ab 96k -sn "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked_ready.mp4"
        TIMEOUT 2
    )

    if not exist "%finaldir%\%%~nf.mp4" (
        COPY "%outputdir%\%%~nf_watermarked_ready.mp4" "%finaldir%\%%~nf.mp4"
        TIMEOUT 2
    )
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: So, it turns out this exact code works fine on another windows 10 machine, with very different hardware (initial machine i9-7900x + gtx1080ti, new machine i3-7100 + gtx1080). Any reason why the code would work on 1 and not the other? The test machine is running driver version 397.64

Comment: Still having issues, even with the simplest of commands:

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar results when other processes were running that had access the the video card.  Just having the programs open(not actively encoding or otherwise requiring hardware acceleration) caused a conflict.